# вызов выбранного события

Tags: javascript

как можно по нажатию на конкретную кнопку с "+" вызывать операцию сложения значений именно того блока, в котором мы хотим это вызвать между span

html

```
<div class="basket_border" id="product1">            
        <div class="selected_product_image">
            <img src="images/product/Без имени-1.jpg" />                           
        </div>                 
        <div class="basket_close" id="close_product1">
            <img src="images/menu/bt_close_login_form.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="">            
            <div class="basket_description"> product description </div>
        </div>
        <div class="basket_price_block">
            <img src="images/personal_cabinet/basket1.png" class="basket_price_image" />
            <div class="basket_price">
                <span id="product1_price">4500</span>
                <span >USD</span>
            </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="basket_counter">
            <div class="basket_minus"> - </div>
            <input class="basket_number" name="basket_number" value="1" />
            <div class="basket_plus"> + </div>
        </div>               
    </div>
            <div class="basket_border" id="product2">            
            <div class="selected_product_image">
                <img src="images/product/Без имени-2.jpg" />                           
            </div>                 
            <div class="basket_close" id="close_product2">
                <img src="images/menu/bt_close_login_form.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="">            
                <div class="basket_description"> product description </div>
            </div>
            <div class="basket_price_block">
                <img src="images/personal_cabinet/basket1.png" class="basket_price_image" />
                <div class="basket_price">
                    <span id="product2_price">4500</span>
                    <span >USD</span>
                </div>            
            </div>
            <div class="basket_counter">
                <div class="basket_minus"> - </div>
                <input class="basket_number" name="basket_number" value="1" />
                <div class="basket_plus"> + </div>
            </div>                   
        </div>    
        <div class="basket_border" id="product3">            
            <div class="selected_product_image">
                <img src="images/product/Без имени-3.jpg" />                           
            </div>                 
            <div class="basket_close" id="close_product3">
                <img src="images/menu/bt_close_login_form.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="">            
                <div class="basket_description"> product description </div>
            </div>
            <div class="basket_price_block">
                <img src="images/personal_cabinet/basket1.png" class="basket_price_image" />
                <div class="basket_price">
                    <span id="product3_price">4500</span>
                    <span >USD</span>
                </div>            
            </div>
            <div class="basket_counter">
                <div class="basket_minus"> - </div>
                <input class="basket_number" name="basket_number" value="1" />
                <div class="basket_plus"> + </div>
            </div>                   
        </div>
```

Comment: к этой структуре вам придется очень сильно модифицировать мой ответ). Изначально пример разметки был совсем другим

Comment: ну что есть то есть)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ с использованием `jquery`

```
/*HTML*/
<div>
<span id="product1_price">1</span>
<div class="basket_plus"> + </div>
</div>

<div>
<span id="product2_price">2</span>
<div class="basket_plus"> + </div>
</div>

<div>
<span id="product3_price">3</span>
<div class="basket_plus"> + </div>
</div>

<div>
<span id="product4_price">4</span>
<div class="basket_plus"> + </div>
</div>

/*JS + JQUERY*/
var sum = 0;
$('.basket_plus').on('click', function() {
  var tmp = $($(this).parent().find('span')).text();
  sum = parseInt(sum)+parseInt(tmp);
  console.log(sum);
});
```

Рабочий пример http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GomWZP

Чистый JS:

```
var sum = 0;
var basket_plus = document.getElementsByClassName('basket_plus');
  for (var i=0; i< basket_plus.length; i++)
  {
    basket_plus[i].addEventListener( "click", function(e) {
      var parent = e.target.parentNode; //переходим к родителю содержащему span с ценой
      var tmp = parent.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML; //берем содержимое span
      sum = parseInt(sum)+parseInt(tmp);
      console.log(sum);
    });
  }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwVZBM

Comment: благодарствую, но как переписать на чистый js с использованием this

Comment: @ddeadlink - Добавил пример на JS

Comment: но в случае если структура html меняется , тогда не получится потащить с тэгов span значения полей

Comment: вам нужно будет просто добраться до другого узла в DOM

Comment: с DOM структурой пока сложновато, но разберемся, спасибо Вам за ответ

Comment: что-то с таким примером значение всегда берется с одного span

Comment: @ddeadlink - в моем примере это не так). Обновите вопрос и приложите код который вы написали.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на чистом *JavaScript*:

```js
function onClick(event) {
    var parent = event.target.parentNode;
    var numField = parent.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
    numField.innerHTML = parseInt(numField.innerHTML) + 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" onclick="onClick(event);">
    <div>
        <span>1</span>
        <button>+</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>1</span>
        <button>+</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>1</span>
        <button>+</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>1</span>
        <button>+</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>1</span>
        <button>+</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вариант без вложенных `div` (но есть тонкость - между `span` и `button` не должно быть ни одного пробельного символа, иначе работает неверно):

```js
function onClick(event) {
    var numField = event.target.previousSibling;
    numField.innerHTML = parseInt(numField.innerHTML) + 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" onclick="onClick(event);">
    <span>1</span><button>+</button>
    <span>1</span><button>+</button>
    <span>1</span><button>+</button>
    <span>1</span><button>+</button>
    <span>1</span><button>+</button>
</div>
```

А следующий код можно использовать и с пробелами между тэгами:

```js
function onClick(event) {
    var numField = event.target;
    do {
        numField = numField.previousSibling;
    } while (numField.nodeType != Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
    numField.innerHTML = parseInt(numField.innerHTML) + 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" onclick="onClick(event);">
    <span>1</span>
    <button>+</button>
    <span>1</span>
    <button>+</button>
    <span>1</span><button>+</button>
    <span>1</span><button>+</button>
    <span>1</span><button>+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: а зачем в таком случае нужна ф-я onLoad

Comment: @ddeadlink Убрать забыл... Поправил.

Comment: поправил html в вопросе. суть как раз в тому что бы js был в отдельном файле и там , как раз куча элементов есть между span и div с "+"